# django manytomany object's field returns empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a couple of classes in a model linked with ManyToManyField:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In a view I am passing:

```
contacts_list = request.user_profile.contacts
```

This produces some strange string of numbers that changes each time the template is refreshed:

```
{% for c in contacts_list %}
    {{ c }}
{% endfor %}
```

This produces nothing:

```
{% for c in contacts_list %}
    {{ c.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

In my Contact class I also have the `__unicode__(self)` defined to return the `first_name`, so why does the `ManyToManyField` object not return this value? I also cannot figure out how to successfully display the `first_name` field values. Thanks for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `all` to view:

```
contacts_list = request.user_profile.contacts.all()
```

or to template:

```
{% for c in contacts_list.all %}
    {{ c.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried all of the solutions I spent hours looking up, including these, but I gave it one more try (the solution in the template) and reset the entire db, and it finally worked.